# How to move a row of one table into another table through select a row and then click to move it using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to stackoverflow i am facing some problem i am working on two tables. It has like right button to move the row into the next table now the actual problem is i am trying to make it but it's not working.

Kindly help me.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on("click", "#submit", function() {
    var getSelectedRows = $(".src-table").parents("tr");
    $(".target-table tbody").append(getSelectedRows);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>
  Source table
</h3>
<table class="src-table">
  <tr>
    <th>Select</th>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit">

<h3>
  Target table
</h3>
<table class="target-table">
  <tr>
    <th>Select</th>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Thanks alot for your time and help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because your selector is incorrect, hence `getSelectedRows` holds an empty jQuery object.

You don't need to use `parents()` at all as the `tr` are children of the table you're selecting, so just `$(".src-table tr");` will work fine.

You should note that I added a `<thead />` element to the tables, otherwise you ended up duplicating the heading row. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on("click", "#submit", function() {
    var getSelectedRows = $(".src-table tbody tr");
    $(".target-table tbody").append(getSelectedRows);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Source table</h3>
<table class="src-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Select</th>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit">

<h3>Target table</h3>
<table class="target-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Select</th>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `var getSelectedRows = $(".src-table").parents("tr");`

with `var getSelectedRows = $(".src-table").find("tr");` worked for me.

here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/53297/)

[`.parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) works with ancestor elements. while [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) works with descendant elements. in you r code `tr` is the child of `.src-table` so you should either use  `$(".src-table").find("tr");` or `$(".src-table tr");`

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
>   .parents() method allows us to **search through the ancestors of these
>   elements** in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the
>   matching elements ordered from immediate parent on up; the elements
>   are returned in order from the closest parent to the outer ones. When
>   multiple DOM elements are in the original set, the resulting set will
>   be in reverse order of the original elements as well, with duplicates
>   removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all TR elements **$(".src-table tr")** and append to the target table. In your function, there is no **tbody**

```
$(function() {
  $('#submit').on('click', function() {
    var getSelectedRows = $(".src-table tr");
    $(".target-table").append(getSelectedRows);
  })
});
```

Comment: `there is no tbody` There is *always* a `tbody`. If you don't define one, then it's added for you.